# Cocoa pods objective c files in Swift project. Bridging issue

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, cocoapods, quickblox

I downloaded code from here:

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk

wich include sample-chat-swift example folder where seems somehow guys created a framework.

In my case if I just use cocoa pods to pull code into my project Xcode says to me that we can't find any of downloaded classes. So I am sure that is problem with bridging but my question what are the steps I need to do to create framework like guys did in theirs example.

Or do I need to bridge each files manually? If so I guess it can take so much time.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own framework for using Tumblr in an app. I'm sure you know how to setup a framework project, but I'll explain what I did when I complied the framework. After you finished the framework what you do is under your xcode project folder in the directory is a fold `Products`. The text for `Project.framework` should be red or black. Either way run your project and make sure its black. Then right click and choose `Show in Finder`. Then you can copy that framework and bring it into the top of the project you want to use the framework in.

[image]

You will also need to make a header file. Like the one I have below if you are using Obj-c, but I'm sure you can google and find an example in swift it you are trying to hide certain aspects of your framework with a swift interface file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//! Project version number for Tumblr.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double TumblrVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for Tumblr.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char TumblrVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements
//#import <Tumblr/Tumblr.h>


#import "TMSDKUserAgent.h"
#import "JXHTTPDataBody.h"
#import "JXHTTPOperationQueueDelegate.h"
#import "TMTumblrAuthenticator.h"
...
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer regarding framework. originally question was about bridging issue. but thanks! I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding bridging issue, guys form QB answered on it:

so using this http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework#Additional_steps_for_Swift_using_CocoaPods

we can simple achieve bridging, even without creating framework.